# Translate: tr does not recognise scandinavian character set

Tags: linux, macos, non-ascii-characters, tr

I wanted to split a file into a word list, which is quite straightforward using `tr`. However, it turns out that are words split at the special Danish characters, e.g.

`echo København Helsingør|tr -c "[:alpha:]" "\n"
K� 
benhavn
Helsing�
r`

Clearly, "ø" is not a member of the `[:alpha:]` set. I get the same result on macOS and Linux. I've tried prefixing the command with

`LC_TYPE=da_DK.UTF-8 echo København Helsingør|tr -c "[:alpha:]" "\n"`

but that gives the same results.

Comment: I believe it's `LC_CTYPE`, not `LC_TYPE`.

Comment: Also, you need to set that for `tr`, not `echo`.

Comment: Typo, sorry. It makes no difference no matter how I attempt to set the locale, I've also tried LC_ALL and LANG.

Comment: See the answer. I get two lines of output, one with `København`, the other with `Helsingør`.

Comment: ...btw, I'm testing on MacOS 10.12.3.

Comment: That's what I want :-) but I cannot reproduce. I'm on macOS 10.12.2.

Comment: Hmm. If I set `LC_CTYPE=C`, I can reproduce your problem, but not otherwise.

Comment: Could you amend the output of `env | egrep '^L'` to your question?

Comment: My default `tr`is from homebrew, it's gnu tr, it works correctly when I use `/usr/bin/tr` Even without setting locale.

Answer (score 1):

`LC_CTYPE` (not `LC_TYPE`) needs to be set for `tr` (not `echo`).

```
$ echo "København Helsingør" | LC_CTYPE=da_DK.UTF-8 tr -c "[:alpha:]" "\n"
København
Helsingør
```

Notably, this is reproducible with the MacOS-native `tr` when setting `LC_CTYPE=C` via the same method:

```
$ echo "København Helsingør" | LC_CTYPE=C tr -c "[:alpha:]" "\n"
K

benhavn
Helsing

r
```

...thus demonstrating that this mechanism is successful in modifying character-class locale settings.

Comment: It's a problem with GNU `tr` from home-brew. Works correctly with native macOS's `/usr/bin/tr`. The home-brew version seems to ignore the locale. Why it's so is another question :-) Thanks!

Comment: You might actually add that as your own answer!

Comment: This is a [known problem for GNU tr](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228558/how-to-make-tr-aware-of-non-asciiunicode-characters). There's been [a bug open](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?23030) since 2008. Very sad.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It's a problem with GNU `tr` from homebrew (`/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/tr`) which is my default, and seems to ignore any setting of the locale. I get the correct word splitting with native macOS's `/usr/bin/tr`.